# Spark Dataframe join: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedAttribute

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe:

[image]

As can be seen, 'origin' is one of the column.

I am trying to join this dataframe with another one:

[image]

```
myDF.join(
    anotherDF,
    anotherDF.col("IATA") === $"origin"
  ).select("City", "State", "date", "delay", "distance", "destination").show()
```

But I get error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported
> literal type class
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedAttribute 'origin

Error message is pretty clear that 'origin' can't be resolved.

What am I missing here, as 'origin' is vary much present in dataframe?

Edit: Spark version is 3.0.0

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-dataframe-join/ this should help.

Comment: `anotherDF.col("IATA") === myDF.col("origin")` <-- and does this work?